# Is there any way to solve ValueEventListner error android Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
}
```

These are the dependencies in my gradle build.
I am getting error with Class Ananomyous class derived from ValueEventListner.

Click to get the error image:

[Error with Class Anonymous Class derived from ValueEventListner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUl73.png)

I am unable to get out from this error any help would be appreciated? 
Here I had another doubt while retriving data from firebase show I use ValueEventListner from client firebase dependency or from firebase database dependency.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please don't just show screenshots of code.  Copy the code into the question to make it easier to read and search.  If there is a compiler error, also state what the error is and where it occurs in the code.

Comment: I will also point out that you're using an extremely old version of the Firebase Realtime Database client library.  You should follow the instructions in the documentation.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backup code that inside **ValueEventlistner**, and Remove **ValueEventlistner** .And Recode **ValueEventListner** becuase **OnDataChange()** not match with super method. I show OnDataChange() it is correct, but may be any library mismatch.